# Netbeans GUI designer can't select empty label

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I have a GUI which i am designing and in a label I removed the text. Now I have no way of selecting the label. I can' find a way to select it. In jformdesigner (which I usually use) it has a tree structure of all the components, however, their is nothing like this in the standard netbeans designer. Also with the annoying designer I can not remove the code for it as it wont let me!!!

I am sure there is something that will display all the components in my frame but not sure what it is and how to use it so all answers greatly appreciated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it's the default Netbeans GUI editor. You can find a tree of the elements in the Navigator window. Window->Navigating->Navigator. (That works for Netbeans 7.2)

Comment: Thanks so much exactly what i needed didn't think it would be called that so didn't try it!!

CHEERS